# Xdebug Problems with Eclipse PHP/PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am having some difficulty using PHP Xdebug with the PHP's internal server provided by later releases of Eclipse. I am running Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). Interestingly enough Xdebug is working quite well with Apache 2, but not the internal PHP server.

Note that the PHP internal server is running. I can use ‘Run As – 1Run on Server’ to run a phpinfo PHP script and a helloworld PHP script. In these cases, the PHP internal server is started with the expected operands. The Linux `ps` command returns:

```
/usr/bin/php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t /home/peter/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/htdocs
```

- Note that port `8000` is used to start the internal PHP server (correctly as best I can tell) and no `–n` operand is specified. This causes the `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` file to be processed (correctly as best I can tell).
- Note that port `80` was originally used to run this server. Of course, port 80 is restricted to root applications. The change to port 8000 was required to get the internal PHP server to start at all.
- Also note that checking ‘Use system default php.ini configuration’ and clearing the PHP ini file (optional) field in the PHP Executable preferences was required to get rid of the `–n` operand.

Also note that I am having some difficulty switching between ‘Run As’ and ‘Debug As’. In some cases I get a message showing that the required port (8000) is already in use. However, I have not found a way to reproduce this problem so far.

Using the procedures described above, the debug internal PHP server was started without the `–n` operand and is processing the php.cli file. The Linux `ps` command returns:

```
/usr/bin/php -S 127.0.0.1:17278 -t /home/peter/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/htdocs
```

One question is why port 17278 was specified, rather then the expected port (8000). Running `phpinfo()` shows that Xdebug appears to be installed in the debug internal web server. A few settings include:

```
xdebug support – enabled
IDE Key – peter (my userid on this machine)
DBGp – Common DeBuGger Protocol - $Revision: 1.145 $
xdebug.remote.enable – on
xdebug.remote.port – 9000
```

I tried to debug `helloworld.php`. The console has the following two messages. The first shows a 404 code. The second shows a 200 code:

> [Sun Apr 22 17:36:20 2018] 127.0.0.1:50358 [404]: /?start_debug=1&debug_fastfile=1&use_remote=1&ZRayDisable=1&send_sess_end=1
>   &debug_session_id=1003&debug_start_session=1&debug_port=10137 - No such file or directory
>
> [Sun Apr 22 17:36:20 2018] 127.0.0.1:50362 [200]: /Server-docroou/helloworld.php?start_debug=1&debug_fastfile=1&use_remote=1&ZRayDisable=1&send_sess_end=1
>   &debug_session_id=1003&debug_start_session=1&debug_port=10137

Note that the debug port is specified as `10137`. Perhaps this is causing the problem. Port 10137 is normally used by the Zend Debugger which I am not using.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you LazyOne. It looks a lot better now.

Comment: The console when I attempted to debug helloworld.php actually had two messages. The first got a 404. The second got a 200. See below.<br/> 
[Sun Apr 22 17:36:20 2018] 127.0.0.1:50358 [404]: /?start_debug=1&debug_fastfile=1&use_remote=1&ZRayDisable=1&send_sess_end=1
&debug_session_id=1003&debug_start_session=1&debug_port=10137 - No such file or directory

[Sun Apr 22 17:36:20 2018] 127.0.0.1:50362 [200]: /Server-docroou/helloworld.php?start_debug=1&debug_fastfile=1&use_remote=1&ZRayDisable=1&send_sess_end=1
&debug_session_id=1003&debug_start_session=1&debug_port=10137

Comment: I have since reviewed the messages that showed up when I attempted to debug helloworld.php. The operands (debug_port=10137, ZRayDisable=1, debug_session_id=1003, etc.) are all zend related. For some reason, PDT id trying to invoke the zend debugger, even though I am not using the zend debugger.

Comment: In such case -- check all settings where you do see PHP Debugger or PHP Interpreter (sorry, never used Eclipse myself so have no idea how it's called there) -- maybe one of such places has Zend Debugger selected instead of Xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed in PDT 6.0 : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533928 ;)